# How to run react js code on eclipse?

Tags: reactjs

I'm not getting how to run reactjs code on eclipse.I have created dynamic web page folder,I tried to run react code but i'm not.I have added react-1.4.jar file to that folder also, but I don't know whether it is correct or not.
Please any one can help me about setup to run react code on eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [CodeMix](https://www.genuitec.com/products/codemix/) to work on Node.js Typescript project with an Angular web application all of these under Eclipse, although, it is not React, it also have support for React projects!!! I would recommend to give it a try, I've already tried to create a CodeMix React Project and it provides a nice example on how to write ReactJS under Eclipse. Hopefully this will get you on the right direction.

Comment: I've just found a nice tutorial about [CodeMix and React](https://www.genuitec.com/react-tutorial-getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

> You can generate bundle.js using web pack that can be placed in
>   eclipse web content folder.

Don't forget to place HTML, CSS, images and other script files.

You can't run the JSX files using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

you can't run react (JSX) codes without babel, webpack. whatever IDE your working with, write a JSX code and compile it by using babel.

There is actually a plugin to support JSX and typescript in Eclipse. It's called "TypeScript". [TypeScript](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript-ide)

follow - official react js documentation [React](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

If you still stuck, try to start react app by using other IDE's like Visual Studio Code, Sublime, Atom.

For Online VS Code IDE react use this : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a2ercy?file=index.html)

Hope this helps